# linkage of qt objects in cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have a library VMSCore which has VMSObject::public QObject.
I implemented factory class which inherit from VMSObject class. 
After I built my library, I try to link it to my exe project.
I get linkage error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl
>   VMS::Factory::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_metacall@Factory@VMS@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl
>   VMS::Algorithm::Factory::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void *
>   *)" (?qt_metacall@Factory@Algorithm@VMS@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) CVFnVMSExperimental C:\Users\Matvey\cvfn\build\Products\CVFnVMS\mocs_compilation.obj    1

As far as I understand the error, I don't link functions defined in moc files.
What is a right way to link moc-created files in CMake?

Comment: Can you inspect the contents of `mocs_compilation.cpp` in your build tree? It should contain one `#include` per `Q_OBJECT` header file. From your error message, it looks like `VMS::Factory` does not contain a `Q_OBJECT` declaration.

Comment: namespace VMS {

 class Factory: public VMS::Object
 {
  Q_OBJECT
 thatäs what I have in Factory class. If I place my Factory /.h and .cpp files in the experimental include and experimental source everything  compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I had to  "set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)" in my cmake file for library.